# Problems understanding d3-example-code in Observable

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I think I have a lag at Basic understanding.
In this Example [Drag (SVG)](https://observablehq.com/@d3/circle-dragging-i?collection=@d3/d3-drag)

I could not get it work.
I wanted to load my database-objects in document.ready function, which works fine but if I want it to make draggable, I think I have some mistakes in understanding the Code.

I thought that .call(drag) is calling a function that attaches the dragged/dragend/drag functions to my objects.
So, naive as I am, I tried to enter drag = {…} as in the example. This obviously is not Right.
So I tried function drag(){…} (outside and inside document.ready-function) - no result.

Now how do I implement this example?
My actual Code:

```js
var svgEditor = d3.select('#drawing');
var symbols = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.UsedProjectSymbols));

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (logLevel >= 5) console.log("svgEditor.js - documentReady - Start");

    var vbArray = newViewBox.split(" ");  //getting actual viewBox-state aout of database
    svgEditor.attr("viewBox", [vbArray[0], vbArray[1], vbArray[2], vbArray[3]]);

    //Symbole aus Datenbank laden
    for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        var symbol = symbols[i];
        const g = svgEditor.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + symbol.SymbolPosition + ")")
            .attr("id", symbol.SubFunctionId.toString())
            .attr("class", "draggable preview")
            .call(drag);
        g.html(symbol.SVG.replace("#{BMK}", symbol.BMK));
    }
    //Tooltip hizufügen
    svgEditor.append("text").attr("id", "tooltip").attr("x", "100").attr("y", "190").attr("visibility", "hidden").text("Tooltip");

    if (logLevel >= 5) console.log("svgEditor.js - documentReady - End");
})
function drag() {
    function dragstarted(d) {
        console.log("d3-dragstarted")
        //d3.select(this).attr("class", "selected");
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        console.log("d3-dragged")
        //d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x = d3.event.x + "," + d.y = d3.event.y + ")");
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        console.log("d3-dragended")
        //    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x = d3.event.x + "," + d.y = d3.event.y + ")");
    }

    return d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended)
}
```

Can please someone explain how to read the Examples on Observable?
Sorry I am bloody beginner in JavaScript-d3

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by now I solved it this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (logLevel >= 5) console.log("svgEditor.js - documentReady - Start");

    var vbArray = newViewBox.split(" ");
    svgEditor.attr("viewBox", [vbArray[0], vbArray[1], vbArray[2], vbArray[3]]);

    //Symbole aus Datenbank laden
    for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
        var symbol = symbols[i];
        const g = svgEditor.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + symbol.SymbolPosition + ")")
            .attr("id", symbol.SubFunctionId.toString())
            .attr("class", "draggable preview")
            .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));
        g.html(symbol.SVG.replace("#{BMK}", symbol.BMK));
    }
    //Tooltip hizufügen
    svgEditor.append("text").attr("id", "tooltip").attr("x", "100").attr("y", "190").attr("visibility", "hidden").text("Tooltip");

    if (logLevel >= 5) console.log("svgEditor.js - documentReady - End");
    function dragstarted(d) {
        console.log("d3-dragstarted");
        //d3.select(this).attr("class", "selected");
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        console.log("d3-dragged");
        //d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x = d3.event.x + "," + d.y = d3.event.y + ")");
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        console.log("d3-dragended");
        //    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x = d3.event.x + "," + d.y = d3.event.y + ")");
    }
})
```

So I changed the call but I'm still interrested in how to read the examples.